# How to make the symlink behaviour of Python's os.walk deterministic across different file ssytem types

Tags: python, filesystems, samba, os.walk, apfs

I have a weird probelm with os.walk in Python 3. To illustrate let's have a directory `fs` with the following structure:

```
fs
├── data1.txt
├── data2.txt
├── data3.txt
├── dir
│   ├── file1.txt
│   ├── file2.txt
│   └── file3.txt
└── sym -> dir
```

###### Test 1: Directory on local volume

Say, this directory sits under macOS on a local disk (APFS filesystem). Now I run the following Python code:

```
for dirpath, subdirs, filenames in os.walk('/path/to/fs'):
    print(f"{dirpath=}\n{subdirs=}\n{filenames=}\n")
```

This returns for me:

```
dirpath='/path/to/fs'
subdirs=['sym', 'dir']
filenames=['data1.txt', 'data3.txt', 'data2.txt']

dirpath='/path/to/fs/dir'
subdirs=[]
filenames=['file2.txt', 'file3.txt', 'file1.txt']
```

Please note, `sym` is listed *as a directory* in the list `subdirs`.

###### Test 2: Directory on a mounted Samba share

Now I copy the directory `fs` to a Samba share (in my case a mounted volume on a Synogly NAS). I run the same Python code

```
for dirpath, subdirs, filenames in os.walk('/path/on/SMB/share/to/fs'):
    print(f"{dirpath=}\n{subdirs=}\n{filenames=}\n")
```

and now I get:

```
dirpath='/path/on/SMB/share/to/fs'
subdirs=['dir']
filenames=['sym', 'data1.txt', 'data3.txt', 'data2.txt']

dirpath='/path/on/SMB/share/to/fs/dir'
subdirs=[]
filenames=['file2.txt', 'file3.txt', 'file1.txt']
```

Please note, `sym` is listed *as a file* in the list `filenames`.

How can I make `os.walk` behaving deterministically the same on both filesystem types? Do I need to go through all eleemnts in the `subdirs` and `filenames` lists, check whether an entry is a symlinks and then myself move it, so that the lists are the same on the two filesystem types?

*Note:* I do not want to set `followlinks=True` in the `os.walk` call, because of the danger of infinite recursion.

##### Additional Details

When I list the directories via `ls` I get the following result:

```
$ ls -l /path/to/fs
total 24
-rw-r--r--@ 1 user  group    8 Feb  7 11:26 data1.txt
-rw-r--r--@ 1 user  group    8 Feb  7 11:26 data2.txt
-rw-r--r--@ 1 user  group    8 Feb  7 11:26 data3.txt
drwxr-xr-x@ 5 user  group  160 Feb  7 11:28 dir
lrwxr-xr-x@ 1 user  group    3 Feb  7 11:29 sym -> dir
```

and

```
ls -l /path/on/SMB/share/to/fs
total 64
-rwx------@ 1 user  group      8 Feb  7 11:26 data1.txt
-rwx------@ 1 user  group      8 Feb  7 11:26 data2.txt
-rwx------@ 1 user  group      8 Feb  7 11:26 data3.txt
drwx------@ 1 user  group  16384 Feb  7 11:28 dir
lrwx------@ 1 user  group   1067 Feb  7 11:31 sym -> dir
```

So both filesystems identify `sym` as a link. Why does Python treat them differently?

Comment: If you run *ls -l /path/on/SMB/share/to/fs* what does *sym* look like? How does it differ from *ls -l /path/to/fs* (if at all)

Comment: @CtrlZ Thanks for chiming in! I have added the output of `ls` to the question. Looks like both filesystems identify `sym` as a link.

Comment: Can you try adding the read and execute flags for group and other (chmod) to both *dir* and *sym*. That's the only obvious difference

Comment: @CtrlZ I cannot: After I do `sudo cmod -R go+r /path/on/SMB/share/to/fs` the permissions on that directory do not change!